# If $E(X^2)$ is finite then $xP(X>x)$ is eventually decreasing?

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, improper-integrals, expectation, monotone-functions

> Assume $X\ge 0$ be a random variable. Does $E(X^2)<\infty$ implies $f(x):=xP(X>x)$ eventually decreasing?

I proved a bunch of things, however that doesn't lead to anywhere.

$E(X^2)\ge E(X^2\mathbb{I}_{(X>x)})\ge x^2E(\mathbb{I}_{(X>x)})=x^2P(X>x)$
which implies $xP(X>x) \le \frac{E(X^2)}{x}$.

Also we have $\displaystyle \int_0^\infty xP(X>x)dx = \frac12E(X^2)$

Any suggestion/help.

Comment: If the integral converges, then the integrant must go to $0$.

Comment: That probably doesnt ensure decreasing

Comment: Yes, there may be jumps I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't have to be decreasing. For example, consider a discrete random variable with $P(X = i) = 2^{-i}$ for $i \in \mathbb{N}_{>0}$ (this is a geometric distribution and all of its moments exist). Then $P(X > x)$ is constant on all the intervals of the form $[n, n + 1)$, so your function $f$ will be increasing within each such interval.

Comment: What happens when pdf exists?

Comment: @Sayan that doesn't matter. By your assumptions $x P(X > x) = x$ for every $x < 0$.

Comment: @Sayan You can also construct counterexamples when a density exists (but they will be more complicated). You just need to choose your density so that it reaches very high values around small intervals near infinity.